# Dot Product to Find Coordinates of $(-3,0,2)$ with respect to the basis $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm to find the coordinates of $(-3,0,2)$ with respect to a basis $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ using the dot product.

Previously I had calculated that Basis to be

$$(1,0,1)\\
(-1,2,1)\\
(2/3,2/3,-2/3)$$

Would I be right to assume that using the dot product simply means scaling each of the above by $(-3,0,2)$?

So:

$$-3(1,0,1) = (-3,0,-3)\\
0(-1,2,1) = (0,0,0)\\
2(2/3,2/3,-2/3) = (4/3, 4/3, -4/3)$$

This doesn't look right to me, wouldn't the coordinates be in the form $(a,b,c)$??

or is it as simple as $(-3a, 0b, 2c)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the basis is an orthogonal one, you can find the coordinates by

$$c_i=\frac{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{u}_i}{||\vec{u}_i||^2}$$

where $\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}$, $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ is the coordinate vector.